# Querying Nested Repeatable Records

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have a schema where a table has a repeatable record 'age', and the structure of that repeatable record is:

{age: 28}

Is it possible to issue a query to search for all rows where the row's 'age' record contains "age = 28 AND age = 56".

So in this data:

[id=1, age: [{age: 28},{age: 56},{age: 62}] ]
[id=2, age: [{age: 28}] ]
[id=3, age: [{age: 28},{age: 56}] ]

only rows 1 and 3 come back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming there are no duplicate ages within the record
and YourTable looks as below

```
id  age  
1    28  
     56  
     62  
2    28  
3    28  
     56
```

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
OMIT RECORD IF SUM(age=28 OR age=56) <> 2
```

or

```
SELECT *, 
  SUM(age=28 OR age=56) WITHIN RECORD AS qualify 
FROM YourTable
HAVING qualify = 2
```

for BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM UNNEST(age) AS a 
        WHERE a  = 28 OR a = 56
       ) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this . Just tried it and it does a full scan of the whole table and takes a long time, versus SELECT * from table WHERE age.age = 28?

Comment: I am not sure I got your point - your query also does full scan! There is nothing in your question about it. Right? The answer reflects the question :o)

Comment: Sorry Mikhail, not sure I was clear. How would I query for rows where it has a record with age=28 AND a record with age=56. I.e. it has to match having both records (not an OR).